# IIS Worker Process: Which DLLs are loaded when different sites reference different versions?

Tags: c#, iis, versioning

IIS 6.0, one root website with Virtual Directories underneath.

The root website has its own `bin` directory, which contains older versions of DLLs... it's a production site, and we don't want to touch it.

Example:

```
CSA.Network.DLL  1.3.9117.0
```

The virtual directory underneath has its `bin` directory, which contains a more recent version of these DLLs, e.g.:

```
CSA.Network.DLL  1.7.8221.0
```

When the IIS worker process launches, it loads the 1.3 version of the DLL... when it loads a page in the virtual directory, will it load 1.7 as well, or will it stick with 1.3 because it's already in memory?

The references are project references, and as such are set to not require a specific type, which leads me to think it will try to use 1.3 and never load 1.7.  Is that correct?  What rules are in effect here?

Thanks!

Comment: The sites will most likely be loaded in different AppDomains. A loaded assembly is scoped at the AppDomain level, thus each site will use it's own version of the assembly.

Comment: I agree with vcsjones. If you are still curious please see the following blog articles which describe using the Fusion log viewer in order to examine assembly binding logs.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments by vcsjones and Sam Shiles cover everything... but to reiterate:

- Sites will run in different AppDomains and as result will get different versions of the DLL.
- If you are worried you can configure sites run in different AppPools
- Make sure there is no version of assembly with the same identity in the GAC - GAC is always taking precedence over any other locations.
- Make sure there is no redirects set for the assemblies for machine or your site.

Comment: Sadly, I was not aware that they would run in different App Domains, even though they were running under the same worker process.  My Windows developer roots are showing through : )  Thanks!